# What is the advantage of setting variables in the controller not the view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, controller

Recently I had to set a few variables with erb in my view, out of necessity, and I noticed how convenient it was to not have to switch between files whenever I wanted to check on or change my variables.

What exactly is the reason that setting variables in the controller is so highly encouraged? Is it just "neater", or does it actually improve load time or something?

Comment: Follow that logic too far and you end up with a single file 5 MB php "application"

Answer (score 1):

Separation between *what* you need to display and *how* you need to display it leads to cleaner code, and code that's easier to change later.

Code in controllers is easier and faster to test than in views, especially if it involves any sort of branching.

Any kind of db lookup directly from a view should be especially avoided.